# Sentencia SQL no valida (interger overflow)

Tags: sql, firebird

Buen día
Necesito hacer un calculo Total del cliente para la forma impresa de los documentos pero a la hora de guardar me sale **Sentencia SQL no valida (interger overflow)**

No tengo problema hacer el calculo en ((DAX) Power pivot) pero en SQL no he podido

DAX Con una consulta previamente importada con ODBC

```
Importe_Sin_Impuesto:=SUMX(Ventas,(([PRECIO_UNITARIO]*[UNIDADES])*((100-Ventas[PCTJE_DSCTO])/100)-[DSCTO_EXTRA]))
```

SQL

```
SELECT CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID, 
       SUM(( DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO * DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES) * (( 100 - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO ) / 100) - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA ) TOTAL_SIN_IMP
FROM CLIENTES CLIENTES_1
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_1.CLIENTE_ID = CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_DET DOCTOS_VE_DET_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_DEST_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_2 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_2.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_FTE_ID)
WHERE  ( DOCTOS_VE_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'r' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_VE_2.ESTATUS = 'P' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_VE_2.MONEDA_ID = 1 )
GROUP BY CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID
```

Es la base de datos de ((Microsip)Firebird 3.0) con el modulo de reporteador que lo estoy intentando

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda

Saludos

Comment: ¿A qué valor asciende esa suma? *interger overflow* indica que el valor desborda la capacidad de un entero. ¿Has pensado en usar un tipo de dato con mayor capacidad como `BIGINT`
?

Comment: Es difícil decir dónde está el problema sin tener los tipos de datos y un ejemplo de los datos que causan este error. Hay que poner atención a los campos enteros, quizás los tipos de datos son muy pequeños para el cálculo que quieres hacer. Lee [este artículo](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq207/) que creo que te será de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque [A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) y [jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate) tienen razón, al investigar un poco vemos que el problema es un poco mas específico: **[The result of an integer operation caused the most significant bit of the result to carry.](http://firebirdfaq.sourceforge.net/faq207/?msclkid=afaddcb0b5b911ec841ee33a59491ca4)**

De modo que aplicando la solución sugerida (definir el formato del número resultante que deseamos usar) tendríamos:

```sql
SELECT CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID, 
       sum( cast( cast(DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO * DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES as numeric(18,3)) * cast((( 100 - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO ) / 100) - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA as numeric(9,6)) as numeric(18,3)) ) AS TOTAL_SIN_IMP
       --SUM(( DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO * DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES) * (( 100 - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO ) / 100) - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA ) TOTAL_SIN_IMP
FROM CLIENTES CLIENTES_1
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_1.CLIENTE_ID = CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_DET DOCTOS_VE_DET_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_DEST_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID)
      INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_2 ON 
     (DOCTOS_VE_2.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_FTE_ID)
WHERE  ( DOCTOS_VE_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'R' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_VE_2.ESTATUS = 'P' )
       AND ( DOCTOS_VE_2.MONEDA_ID = 1 )
GROUP BY CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID;
```

- (en mi caso requiere mayúscula aquí DOCTOS_VE_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'R')

--

Para mejor legibilidad te sugiero un subquery del estilo:

```sql
SELECT 
    CLIENTE_ID, 
    sum( cast( cast(IMPORTE as numeric(18,3)) * cast(DSCTO_TOTAL as numeric(9,6)) as numeric(18,3)) ) AS TOTAL_SIN_IMP
from(
    SELECT 
        CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID, 
        DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID,
        DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES,
        DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO * DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES AS IMPORTE,
        DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO,
        DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA,
        ((( 100 - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO ) / 100) - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA ) AS DSCTO_TOTAL
        --   SUM(( DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PRECIO_UNITARIO * DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.UNIDADES) * (( 100 - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.PCTJE_DSCTO ) / 100) - DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DSCTO_EXTRA ) TOTAL_SIN_IMP
    FROM CLIENTES CLIENTES_1
         INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_1 
            ON DOCTOS_VE_1.CLIENTE_ID = CLIENTES_1.CLIENTE_ID
         INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_DET DOCTOS_VE_DET_1 
             ON DOCTOS_VE_DET_1.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID
         INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1 
            ON DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_DEST_ID = DOCTOS_VE_1.DOCTO_VE_ID
         INNER JOIN DOCTOS_VE DOCTOS_VE_2 
            ON DOCTOS_VE_2.DOCTO_VE_ID = DOCTOS_VE_LIGAS_1.DOCTO_VE_FTE_ID
    WHERE TRUE 
        AND DOCTOS_VE_1.TIPO_DOCTO = 'R'
        AND DOCTOS_VE_2.ESTATUS = 'P'
        AND DOCTOS_VE_2.MONEDA_ID = 1)
GROUP BY CLIENTE_ID;
```